# Why does calling std::stringstream's good() through a pointer lead to crashes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am having problems with a stringstream object. My class has an input stream as a member.
I am checking if obj->istream and after thatn if obj->istream->good().

The stream exists but the call to good() crashes. I am in Visual Studio 2005. Any clue?

How do I reset an istream?

```
if (soap->is) { 

  if (soap->is->good())

      return soap->is->read(s, (std::streamsize)n).gcount();

    return 0;
}
```

that code is from gsoap framework

```
std::istringstream in_stream;
in_stream.str("a buffer");
soap->is = &in_stream;
```

the in_stream goes out of scope, it belongs to a local stack, however the ->is->good()
is called outside that function when in_stream no longer exists.

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: You're doing the equivalent of calling a doctor, telling him that you hurt, but not where, how, or why you think you might be hurting. Where is the code?

Comment: @Bertrand: Didn't the use of operator arrow (`->`) tell you that? :)

Comment: @Billy, it did, that is precisely why I asked. "crashes" doesn't say much about the kind of issue the OP is getting. Could be a compilation error.

Comment: @Bertrand: Good point. Though I've never associated "crashes" with "compile-time error", but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Wow, "stringstream is not good()" vs. "calling a member function through a pointer crashes" is a hell of a difference. I've fixed your question's title.

Comment: @sbi: Modified your modification a bit .. hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably indicates that your `is` member does not point to a `stringstream`. It might just be initialized to some garbage value when enclosing object is instantiated.

If you are testing for pointer being zero, make sure it's set to zero in the constructor (and reset to zero if you ever detach the stream).

Comment: +1 for pointing out lack of initialization -- that's the most likely cause here.

Answer (score 4):

You've answered the question in the last two lines. You have a dangling pointer to an object that's gone out of scope, and using it will cause undefined behaviour (which could well be a crash). You need to make sure the object exists for as long as it's needed, by placing it in a longer-lasting scope or allocating it with `new` and making sure it is deleted when no longer needed.

Comment: If allocating with `new`, it should be going into some form of smart pointer, be it `std::auto_ptr`, or some form of scoped or shared pointer.

Comment: Or just return a string by value from `.str()`, since all OP does with the pointer is (attempt to) get the data from it.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior somewhere else in your program -- my guess would be that you actually casted that pointer into a `std::istream`, even though it is not. We would need to see where `in` is instantiated before being able to run down exactly what's going on. Look for any casts to `istream` in your codebase and I bet you find the problem.